# Azure App Services - Can't find certificate by thumbprint

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I have a B1 App Service in Azure and I've installed my certificate in it as shown below:
[image]

When I try to get the certificate, it can't find it. As if no certificates are installed. Here's my code:

```
using (X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
    certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
        X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
        certificateThumbprint,
        false);

    if (certCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        return certCollection[0];
    }

    throw new Exception("Certificate not found!");
}
```

I've verified the certificate thumbprint and even tried putting it hard-coded as string.

When I try to print the number of certificates in the store like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("certStore.Certificates.Count : " + certStore.Certificates.Count);
```

it returns zero certificates.

I also tried changing `StoreName` and `StoreLocation` - still same result. And even when not giving any `StoreName` or `StoreLocation` it still doesn't find any certificates.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**You need to add an app setting called: `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES`**

From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/?v=17.23h:

> Adding an app setting named WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES with its value set to the thumbprint of the certificate will make it accessible to your web application. You can have multiple comma-separated thumbprint values or can set this value to “ * “ (without quotes) in which case all your certificates will be loaded to your web applications personal certificate store.

Comment: FYI, you can use the powershell console in Kudu to navigate to the following path and then run a LS command on it cert:\localmachine\currentuser

Comment: Thanks! I configured it 2 years ago to a specific certificate and couldn't figure out why the function wouldn't load the updated certificate. This post triggered an aha moment. Thx !!!